# New to python, question about organizing data set for analysis

Tags: python

I have a bunch of data sets that I need to analyse and I'm not sure what is the optimal or "standard" way to organize my data in python.

For visualization, here is the general structure, where each "data type" is a 1- or 2-D array:

Data set

- session 1

- ```
   data type 1 (length x)
  ```
- ```
   data type 2 (len Y)
  ```
- ```
   data type 3 (len z)
  ```

- session 2

- ```
   data type 1 (len a)
  ```
- ```
   data type 2 (len Y)
  ```
- ```
   data type 3 (len c)
  ```

etc...

My analysis will usually involve performing some action to compare a data type between sets. Each data type always has the same number of dimensions between sessions, but **the length of each data type array between sessions is not fixed**, so I can't simply create n-dimensional arrays for each type of data.

**I want to be able to group all my data instead of needing a separate list for each data type** (Similar to using structures/cells in MATLAB). **Is it best to use a dictionary for each session, then a dictionary within the session key for each data type, or if there is a better way to structure the data,** such as using a dictionary for sessions, but a nested list or maybe pd dataframe for the data types? Thanks

Comment: Check around in your field what is commonly used. This is very much dependent on what your analysis involves, and a bunch of other factors.

Comment: You may still be able to use NumPy arrays instead, even if the length is variable. A Pandas Dataframe is not suitable if these arrays are just plain numbers; a dataframe is for much more structured data (a "table").

Comment: Depends on your data. If you share your data people can give suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using [xarray](http://xarray.pydata.org), which might make it easier to select data along various dimensions of your dataset.

If you know in advance which sorting operations you will want to perform, you could construct your structure from native types, as you describe. In my experience however, the most useful shape changes while working with the data and it's desirable to stay flexible.

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot for the suggestion. I've been playing around with this a bit, but I think if I use an xarray DataArray where each row has a variable length, I lose a lot of functionality like the coordinate system and dimension labels. So to get around this, I'd have to store everything in it's own dataset. But I don't see why this is better than a dictionary. Am I wrong about not being able to use DataArray, or otherwise could you explain the advantage?

Comment: Two Arguments:

Storing each session in a DataSet lets you associate all kind of metadata to it, like date, participants, or whatever else is relevant. Putting this in a dictionary name gets unwieldy quickly, putting it in a field within the dictionary means you are slowly building a data storage structure yourself, when others have previously done it for you.

Displaying a data set is much easier an cleaner than looking at what is in your dictionary. 

I suggest you build a mock dataset in each implementation xarray and nested dict, and compare what is easier to handle.

Comment: Ah yep that makes a lot of sense, thanks for the explanation. I actually had played around with a mock data set but I wasn't supplying any metadata to the data set, I now better understand the advantages of a dataset over a dictionary for this kind of data so ty

Comment: Glad I could help :) 

Two tips in case you are new to Stackoverflow: Questions should typically be *much* more specific, with a minimum working example of code that produces a different outcome than you expect or want, tags and a precise description of the kind of answer you are looking for. Asking for advice typically gets removed. Also, comments are not intended for discussion. The idea is your question gets a definite answer. If that does not satisfy your requirements, you´re meant to modify your question or ask a new one. But I like giving advice :)